# repmat, the size of matrix or number of use

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix for which I extract each column and do `repmat` function for each of them to build another matrix. Since i I have to do this for a large number of vectors(each column of my first matrix) it takes so long(relative to which I expect). If I do this for the whole matrix and then do something to build them, does it takes less time?

Consider this as an example:

```
A=[1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9]
```

I want to produce these

```
A1=[1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
    1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
    1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
A2=[4 5 6 4 5 6 4 5 6
    4 5 6 4 5 6 4 5 6
    4 5 6 4 5 6 4 5 6]
A3=[7 8 9 7 8 9 7 8 9
    7 8 9 7 8 9 7 8 9
    7 8 9 7 8 9 7 8 9]
```

Comment: Why won't you use a 3D array instead of cluttering workspace with three variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to @thewaywewalk's answer and using kron and repmat:

```
clear

A=[1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9];

B = repmat(kron(A',ones(3,1)),1,3);


A1 = B(1:3,:)
A2 = B(4:6,:)
A3 = B(7:end,:)
```

Which results in the following:

```
A1 =

     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3


A2 =

     4     5     6     4     5     6     4     5     6
     4     5     6     4     5     6     4     5     6
     4     5     6     4     5     6     4     5     6


A3 =

     7     8     9     7     8     9     7     8     9
     7     8     9     7     8     9     7     8     9
     7     8     9     7     8     9     7     8     9
```

Or as @Divakar pointed out, it would be advisable to create a single 3D array and store all your data in it (general solution):

```
n = 3; %// # of times you want to repeat the arrays.

A=[1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9];

B = repmat(kron(A',ones(n,1)),1,n);
C = zeros(n,n*size(A,2),3);

C(:,:,1) = B(1:n,:);
C(:,:,2) = B(n+1:2*n,:);
C(:,:,3) = B(2*n+1:end,:);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try if this fits your needs:

```
A = [1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9];
n = 3;  %// size(A,1)

cellArrayOutput = arrayfun(@(x) repmat( A(:,x).',n,n ), 1:size(A,2), 'uni',0)
```

instead of different variable names, everything is stored in a cell array.

if you insist on different names, I'd recommend to use structs:

```
A = [1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9];
n = 3;

structOutput = struct;
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    structOutput.(['A' num2str(ii)]) = repmat( A(:,ii).', n, n );
end
```

which gives you:

```
>> structOutput.A1

ans =

     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
```

and so on.

I don't expect to much performance plus, you should share your full code for further help.

Comment: Nice solution. If you like to have the variables directly in your workspace, you could instead use `assignin('base', ['A' num2str(ii)], repmat( A(:,ii).', n, n ))` in the loop.

Comment: @JandeGier, I know but I wouldn't consider it as a good solution at all.